# Custom UnmarshalBSON in mongo-go-driver

Tags: go, mongo-go

I would like to have some kind of a "hook" that runs whenever I get a specific type of object from the database. I thought the [`Unmarshaler`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#Unmarshaler) interface is perfect for that, but... How can I implement that interface without manually unmarshalling every single field myself?

I thought of doing something like this:

```
func (t *T) UnmarshalBSON(b []byte) error {
    // Simply unmarshal `b` into `t` like it would otherwise
    bson.Unmarshal(b, t) // Obviously this won't work, it'll be an infinite loop
    // Do something here
    return nil
}
```

How could I achieve this without manually unmarshalling the fields using the reflect pkg?

Comment: Not sure if that's the best way, but it will work https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/904f0fdad34eaac09c5d53098f960c5c#file-struct_custom_unmarshal-go-L15.

Answer (score 7):

Make another type. It will inherit fields, but not methods. Therefore no infinite loop here.

```
func (t *T) UnmarshalBSON(b []byte) error {
    type Alias T
    bson.Unmarshal(b, (*Alias)(t))
    // Do something here
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.